# the continuous functions with norm

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, distribution-theory, holder-spaces

I'm having trouble trying to understand what does means the first expression in particular 
the last term in it

should we add $\|f\|_{\infty} \leq \infty$ or what i can't see what is his role ($\|f\|_{\infty}$) here

\begin{align*}
 {C}(\mathbb{R}^{n})&=\{f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\longmapsto \mathbb{R}: \text{continue},\lim_{\|{x}\|\to \infty }f(x)=0,\|{f}\|_{\infty}\}\\
 {C}_{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})&=\{ f \in {C}: \text{of compact support } \mathbb{R}^{n}  \} \\
 Lip_{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})&=\{f \in C_{0}: \exists M: |f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y| \} \\
 \overline{Lip_{0}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})&={C}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \\
 \mathcal{D}(\Omega)=\mathcal{C}_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})&=\{f \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty} : \text{ of compact support  } \} 
\end{align*}

would you please  also explain how  $\lim_{\|{x}\|\to \infty }f(x)=0,$ implies $\|{f}\|_{\infty} \leq \infty$
[image]

Comment: $||f||_\infty$ denotes $\sup_{\mathbb{R}} |f|$. It is usually taken as a norm in $C(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @ABC so it's normal to take it without add $\leq \infty$ ??

Comment: Maybe not, but notice that a continuous function with $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$ will necessarily have $||f||_\infty<\infty$.

Comment: @ABC Scanning your handwriting instead of using MathJax is frowned upon by quite a few people here, and I can't say I blame then. To be honest, I often vote to close such questions - but here the handwriting is reasonably legible here, so I didn't. Still, it would probably been have *less* hassle for the OP to type this using MathJax instead of scanning...

Comment: @ABC This has absolutely nothing to do with the *level* of the question. If you check my profile, you'll find that I often answer relatively basic question. But if the one who *asks* a question demonstrates that he feels it's not worth his time to make it easy to read, then *that* IMHO shows that he doesn't appreciate the time and effort of the people who might answer it. But as I already said - this question was OK anyway - not great maybe, but OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to answer your question:

let $$f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R, \quad \text{continuous},\quad \lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=0.$$

Fix $\varepsilon >0$; then by definition of the limit there exists $R>0$ such that $|f(x)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x|>R$. On the compact set $\{|x|\le R\}$ the function $|f|$ is continuous, hence attains its supremum and infimum (Veierstrass theorem). Therefore, $$\|f\|_\infty\le \max(\varepsilon, \sup_{|x|\le R}|f(x)|)<\infty.$$

As for notations, it's a bit weird to see $C(\Bbb R^n)$ defined as a space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity. In most cases, this notation is reserved for the space of continuous functions. Then you can define $C_b$ as the space of continuous bounded functions, $C_0$ as a space of continuous vanishing functions, $C_c$ as a space of continuous function with compact support, etc.